# Swing components not moving to desired cell in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a simple UI for a program that can read a file, write to a file and search for text within a file. I have most of my Components created, the problem is that they're all being "drawn" in the same (center) cell. I've tried applying weights, widths, etc. all to no avail.

Here's my base code for the UI:

```
public void GUI(){

    //Create main window for Program
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Simple Data Base");     //Init frame
    mainWindow.setSize(500, 400);       //Set frame size
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);        //Make frame visible

    //Create panel for the main window of the GUI
    JPanel simpleGUI = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    simpleGUI.setBackground(Color.cyan);

    //Create button linking to read function
    JButton readButton = new JButton("Read");       //Init button, and give text
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 0;
    gbCons.gridy = 1;

    //Create button linking to the search function
    JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 1;
    gbCons.gridy = 1;

    //Create label prompting user to specify desired function
    JLabel promptText = new JLabel("Click 'Read' to read a file, 'Search' to search within a file, 'Write' to write to a file:");
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 0;
    gbCons.gridy = 0;

    //Add components to Main window
    mainWindow.getContentPane().add(simpleGUI);
    simpleGUI.add(promptText, gbCons);
    simpleGUI.add(readButton, gbCons);
    simpleGUI.add(searchButton, gbCons);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the problem is that they're all being "drawn" in the same (center) cell.

```
simpleGUI.add(promptText, gbCons);
simpleGUI.add(readButton, gbCons);
simpleGUI.add(searchButton, gbCons);
```

You are using the same GridBagConstraints for each component so the contraints are identical for each component.

You neeed to:

1. set the constraints
2. add the component to the panel using the constraints
3. repeat steps 1 and 2.

For example:

```
JButton readButton = new JButton("Read"); 
gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbCons.gridx = 0;
gbCons.gridy = 1;
simpleGUI.add(readButton, gbCons);

JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbCons.gridx = 1;
gbCons.gridy = 1;
simpleGUI.add(searchButton, gbCons);
```

I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

Download the demo code and use that example as your starting code. The demo code will show you how to better structure your class by:

1. NOT extending JFrame
2. Creating the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread
3. Use the pack() method, NOT the setSize(...) method
4. Make the frame visible AFTER all components have been added to the frame

Comment: Thanks, moving the individual "add" statements to their corresponding Components - instead of grouping them all together - worked. Exolains why I couldn't find anything about it in the Swing Doc.

Comment: Another really good LayoutManager tutorial by Scott Stanchfield can be found [here](http://javadude.com/articles/layouts/).  His explanation of GridBagLayout was the first that I ever read that made sense to me back in 1998.